# Dante socks error "local client closed" and "0: local client error (Connection reset by peer)"

Tags: proxy, socks5

I have installed and to my best knowledge configured Dante to use Socks5 on it. However I still can't connect to it using anything. I get a bung of different errors in the socks.log file. 
My sockd.conf file is as follows:

```
logoutput: /var/log/socks.log

internal: ens160 port = 1085
external: ens160 port = 1085


socksmethod: none
user.privileged: root
user.notprivileged: nobody

client pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: error connect disconnect
}


client block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}

socks pass {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: error connect disconnect
}

socks block {
        from: 0.0.0.0/0 to: 0.0.0.0/0
        log: connect error
}
```

This is a bit of my log:

```
May 11 17:19:04 (1526073544.856843) sockd[19202]: info: block(1): tcp/accept ]: 151.242.196.69.62400 142.54.179.81.1085: negotiate timeout  after 31 seconds 
May 11 17:19:05 (1526073545.664149) sockd[19202]: info: pass(1): tcp/accept [: 151.242.196.69.62422 142.54.179.81.1085
May 11 17:19:06 (1526073546.025996) sockd[19219]: info: pass(1): tcp/connect [: 151.242.196.69.62422 142.54.179.81.1085 -> 142.54.179.81.62422 149.154.175.50.443
May 11 17:19:06 (1526073546.261682) sockd[19202]: info: pass(1): tcp/accept [: 151.242.196.69.62423 142.54.179.81.1085
May 11 17:19:06 (1526073546.625768) sockd[19219]: info: pass(1): tcp/connect [: 151.242.196.69.62423 142.54.179.81.1085 -> 142.54.179.81.62423 149.154.175.50.443
May 11 17:19:07 (1526073547.738340) sockd[19202]: info: pass(1): tcp/accept [: 151.242.196.69.62427 142.54.179.81.1085
May 11 17:19:07 (1526073547.738474) sockd[19202]: info: block(1): tcp/accept ]: 151.242.196.69.62402 142.54.179.81.1085: negotiate timeout after 30 seconds
May 11 17:19:08 (1526073548.225382) sockd[19202]: info: block(1): tcp/accept ]: 151.242.196.69.62427 142.54.179.81.1085: error after reading 3 bytes in 1 second: eof from local client
May 11 17:19:08 (1526073548.225723) sockd[19202]: info: block(1): tcp/accept ]: 151.242.196.69.62403 142.54.179.81.1085: negotiate timeout after 30 seconds
May 11 17:19:15 (1526073555.399365) sockd[19202]: info: pass(1): tcp/accept [: 151.242.196.69.62434 142.54.179.81.1085
May 11 17:19:16 (1526073556.147912) sockd[19202]: info: pass(1): tcp/accept [: 151.242.196.69.62435 142.54.179.81.1085
May 11 17:19:18 (1526073558.359153) sockd[19202]: info: pass(1): tcp/accept [: 151.242.196.69.62436 142.54.179.81.1085
May 11 17:19:20 (1526073560.421618) sockd[19202]: info: block(1): tcp/accept ]: 151.242.196.69.62410 142.54.179.81.1085: negotiate timeout after 31 seconds
May 11 17:19:22 (1526073562.268207) sockd[19202]: info: pass(1): tcp/accept [: 151.242.196.69.62438 142.54.179.81.1085
May 11 17:19:22 (1526073562.385487) sockd[19202]: info: pass(1): tcp/accept [: 151.242.196.69.62437 142.54.179.81.1085
May 11 17:19:23 (1526073563.772540) sockd[19202]: info: pass(1): tcp/accept [: 151.242.196.69.62439 142.54.179.81.1085
May 11 17:19:23 (1526073563.882074) sockd[19219]: info: pass(1): tcp/connect ]: 0 -> 151.242.196.69.62313 142.54.179.81.1085 -> 0, 0 -> 142.54.179.81.62313 149.154.175.50.443 -> 0: local client error (Connection reset by peer).  Session duration: 133s
May 11 17:19:23 (1526073563.882167) sockd[19219]: info: pass(1): tcp/accept ]: 0 -> 151.242.196.69.62313 142.54.179.81.1085 -> 0: local client error (Connection reset by peer).  Session duration: 133s
May 11 17:19:25 (1526073565.344443) sockd[19202]: info: block(1): tcp/accept ]: 151.242.196.69.62439 142.54.179.81.1085: error after reading 3 bytes in 2 seconds: Connection reset by peer
```

Can you please help me figure this out?